# Ubuntu 20.04 Change Workspace Via Shortcut Key

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome

Maybe about a year ago, I had an extension for gnome-shell that enabled me to switch between workspaces using shortcut keys, for example:

```
ctl + 1 = Workspace 1 
ctl + 2 = Workspace 2
ctl + 3 = Workspace 3
ctl + 4 = Workspace 4
ctl + 5 = Workspace 5
ctl + 6 = Workspace 6
ctl + 7 = Workspace 7
ctl + 8 = Workspace 8
ctl + 9 = Workspace 9
```

However, I had to do a fresh install and now I don't seem to be able to find the extension on `extensions.gnome.org`.

Is anyone else currently using this extension, if so can you remind me of the name?  Am I describing the sub-function of a parent extension?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thumbs up to whoever voted up my question. I was motivated to resolve this issue before morning tea.

In Ubuntu 20.04, perhaps in a futile manner to avoid any possible conflicts or mishaps, I used their native options under:  Settings // Keyboard Shortcuts as to set `Ctrl+1`, `Ctrl+2`, `Ctrl+3`, and `Ctrl+4` to my first 4 workspaces (workspace 1 is a little weird).  Then to set my other workspaces, I installed dconf-editor (not a gnome-shell extension, hence my previous foggy brain problem not being to find it) and I assigned workspaces 5 through 10 using: `['<Primary>X']` (Where `X` is the number of the relevant workspace and `Primary` = `Ctrl`)

dconf-editor is `*dangerous*` app that can break things, so the correct path to your workspace settings: `[checkmark] / org / gnome / desktop / wm / keybindings / switch-to-workspace-X`

Answer (score 0):

###### In my case I wanted to switch to a workspace using GSettings tool and Primary + Left Alt + Numpad keys on Ubuntu 22.04.

###### You can copy paste snippets to list default keybindings and set shortcuts for 9 workspaces:

###### List Keybindings:

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings | grep switch-to-workspace
```

###### Switch to Workspace (1-9):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-1 "['<Primary><Alt>KP_1']" &&
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-2 "['<Primary><Alt>KP_2']" &&
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-3 "['<Primary><Alt>KP_3']" &&
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-4 "['<Primary><Alt>KP_4']" &&
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-5 "['<Primary><Alt>KP_5']" &&
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-6 "['<Primary><Alt>KP_6']" &&
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-7 "['<Primary><Alt>KP_7']" &&
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-8 "['<Primary><Alt>KP_8']" &&
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-9 "['<Primary><Alt>KP_9']"
```